# minimum value of square of normal distribution

Tags: self-study, order-statistics

I am given that $X_1, X_2,....,X_n)$ are $N(0,\sigma^2)$, and A=minimum value of $(X_1^2, X_2^2,...X_n^2)$, and need to find the smallest value of n such that $P(A<0.004)>0.90$ when $\sigma^2=1$.

My query is whether this is equivalent to  ..find the smallest value of n such that $P(X<\sqrt{0.004)}>0.90$ when $\sigma^2=1$.

This does not feel correct but I am not sure what is the flaw in this approach

Comment: One way: (a) the distribution of the iid $X_i^2$'s is a .... distribution; (b) the minimum of the iid $X_i^2$'s is called an order statistic; (c) the distribution of the first order statistic is given by ... Another way: $\mathbb P(\min(X_1^2, X_2^2,...X_n^2)<0.004)=1-\mathbb P(\min(X_1^2, X_2^2,...X_n^2)>0.004)$ and the last term can be easily expressed in terms of $\mathbb P(X_1^2>0.004)$

Comment: If we just need to evaluate $P(Xi^2>0.004)$, is the $\sigma^2=1$ relevant

Comment: It is relevant if, when changing the value of $\sigma$, the value of the probability changes. (Hint: check for `scale parameter`.)

Comment: You seem to overlook the possibility that $X\lt 0,$ something that has a chance of $1/2$ of occurring for each of the $X_i.$